# If using the -t option, how does PIP know if the Python is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: python, pip

You can specify the Python version with a flag (pip install --python-version 3.6 ...), but you can't seem to specify whether you want to install a module that is 32-bit or 64-bit.  I have some theories, but its behavior is unclear to me on this point.

To be more specific, I want to use PIP.exe to install a module in an embedded Python area (which does not have its own PIP.exe) using the -t flag to specify the location.

Update:  What seems to be the case is that a 32-bit Pip installs to 32-bit Pythons, and a 64-bit Pip installs for 64-bit Pythons.

Comment: Do you have both versions in your executable/environment variables? I think that matters more than any arguments you add with pip. -t just gives the directory you want to install it in?

Comment: Can you clarify what the "embedded Python area" is? What device are you targeting?

Comment: I am targeting a separate embedded Python area.  It is contained and only run by a parent process.

Answer (score 1):

> You can specify the Python version with a flag,

You cannot. Option `-t` for `pip install` sets the target **directory**, not Python version.

> but you can't seem to specify whether you want to install a module that is 32-bit or 64-bit.

`pip` is a Python script, it runs under a Python interpreter and the interpreter certainly knows if it's 32- or 64-bit.

> To be more specific, I want to use PIP.exe to install a module in an embedded Python area

You can **download** packages for a different (from the current Python/pip) hardware platform, OS and Python version but you cannot **install** them. To install packages you must have a compatible `pip`. So first thing is to install `pip` for said embedded Python.

Comment: --python-version sets the Python version.  It seems the to install a 32-bit module, one needs a 32-bit Pip.

Comment: Have you tried it? Try to install something complex with binary extensions: numpy, scipy, pandas. Try to create a virtualenv with Python **2.7** and install pandas for Python **3.7**.

Comment: I haven't used a Python 2 Pip, but any Python 3 Pip seems to work, as long as it is the same bit width (32 or 64) for the destination Python.  By 'compatible', do you mean same bit width?  Pip seems to have its own version number.

Comment: By 'compatible' I mean the same platform, same OS, same Python version. Bitness is the least interesting here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing something like trying to pull a package off of PyPI using a local `pip` and dump them into a folder on something like a CircuitPython device, you could try the following:

```
pip install \
      --no-compile \
      --target /your/path \
      --python-version=3.5 \
      --implementation=py \
      --no-binary=:all: \
      --no-deps \
      adafruit-circuitpython-bmp280
```

That will dump the sources (modules or packages) into `/your/path`. The `--python-version` only uses the tags in the package and doesn't actually check the sources. `--implementation=py` will force it to use pure-python packages

---

**Older answer, but useful for some context**

> You can specify the Python version with a flag.

Can you clarify this? Are you talking about running something like `python3.5` or `python3.8`? That's the name of the Python binary.

You may also be using Windows, where [you can include `-32` or `-64` as a suffix](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines) to the executable in the shebang line. The line is processed by the `py` [PEP-397 launcher](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/).

---

To eliminate confusion, the [best practice](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#basic-usage) is to not run `pip install ...` but instead `python -m pip install ...`. You're then assured that the `pip` and `python` are for the same installation (version, virtual environment, etc.)

For example, if I have Python 2.7, Python 3.5, and Python 3.8 installed, I might have the following 'unambiguous' binaries on my path

- `python2`
- `python2.7`
- `python3.5`
- `python3.8`

However, there's also

- `python`
- `python3`
- `pip`
- `pip3`

What those actually point is anyone's guess and could depend on the install order, how they were installed, and any manual path manipulations. In some setups, `pip` might install to (e.g.) the Python 3.5 version while `python` is Python 2.7. If that were the case, if you ran `pip install requests` then `python -c "import requests"` it would fail.

To tie it back to [the launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) if you're on Windows, running `py -3.7-32 myscript.py` would run your script with the 32-bit version of Python 3.7, if it exists. If you needed to install a package for it, use `py -3.7-32 -m pip install ...` to ensure it is installed for it, rather than `pip install ...` which will go who-knows-where.

Comment: Embedded Python installations don't seem to have Scripts directories and therefore do not have Pip, or even a place to put it.  (Maybe I am confused.)